# linux bash script unzip to same directory

Tags: bash, unzip

I have this bash script that unzips a bunch of password protected files, but it unzips to my main directory and not to the same folder the zip files are in which I need it to. I didn't originally write this and have no experience writing bash scripts so I have no idea what to try

```
#/bin/sh
for file in *.zip
do
unzip -P pcp9100 "$file" -d ../ 
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "-d" option. You script basically providing it a path of "../" which is your main directory. Use the below script

> ```
> #/bin/sh
> for file in *.zip
> do
> unzip -P pcp9100 "$file"  
> done
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I got it now. I still need the `-d` option but I removed one dot and it unzipped to the same directory:

```
#/bin/sh
for file in *.zip
do
unzip -P pcp9100 "$file" -d ./ 
done
```

Answer (score -1):

This one liner also works like a charm, a variation on the answers above

$ for file in `ls *.zip`; do unzip $file -d `echo $file | cut -d . -f 1`; done